# Unexpected revents value in poll for non blocking socket connect

Tags: c, sockets, polling

I am trying to create a non-blocking socket connect. Below is the code for the same

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#define MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS 64

void perror(char const * s);

int main()
{
    int result, n, rc;
    socklen_t result_len = sizeof(result);
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    int sockfd, flags;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int len = sizeof(int);
    flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(20000);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.17");
    n = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if (n != 0)
        //if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
        perror("Connection gone wrong");

    fds[0].fd = sockfd;
    fds[0].events  = POLLOUT;
    fds[0].revents = 0;
    while(1){
         rc = poll(fds, (nfds_t)1, 10*1000);
         printf("value of poll result is - %d- %d\n", rc, errno);
         if (rc == 1){
             getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &result, &result_len);
             printf("%d\n", result);
         }
         printf("code for POLLOUT - %d\n", POLLOUT);
         printf("revents - %d\n", fds[0].revents);
         if(result == 0){
              break;
         }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Connection gone wrong: Operation now in progress
value of poll result is - 1- 115
111
code for POLLOUT - 4
revents - 28
value of poll result is - 1- 115
0
code for POLLOUT - 4
revents - 20
```

As per the `poll` documentation

> The field revents is an output parameter, filled by the kernel with the events that actually occurred. The bits returned in revents can include any of those specified in events, or one of the values POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL. (These three bits are meaningless in the events field, and will be set in the revents field whenever the corresponding condition is true.)

When I print the value of `revents`, that is set to a different value to `POLLOUT`. Is this the exact behaviour of `poll()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `poll.revents` is a bitfield.

From the header file `poll.h`

```
#define POLLIN          0x0001
#define POLLPRI         0x0002
#define POLLOUT         0x0004
#define POLLERR         0x0008
#define POLLHUP         0x0010
#define POLLNVAL        0x0020
```

So your value `0x28` is comprised of `POLLERR|POLLNVAL`, which can occur, when the filedescriptor polled for is not open:

> ```
>   POLLNVAL
>          Invalid request: fd not open (only returned in revents; ignored in events).
> ```

These values can always occur, even when not asked for in `poll.events`.

As you can see, the socket error is `111` (first call to `getsockopt()`), which means `Connection refused`. After this, the filedescriptor is invalid to poll for, because it is no longer connected.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. In the second case, the value of `revents` is 20 which is `POLLNVAL` so does it indicate that the socket is not ready for writing? I am still able to write to the socket though.

Comment: @wonder You should not be able to write to a socket, that is not connected. It should return an `EPIPE`, check the return value

Comment: Yes I am sorry. It is not able to write if `revents` is 20. It is only able to write when the `revents` is 4. I just got confused between 20 and 4. Thank you.